# Windows Phone list picker with empty default value

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have scenario where I need to select country from drop down or list picker. I have found how to make this list, but I need to have a default value in this drop-down and I want the default value to be null.

Can someone suggest the best way how to make something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the SelectedItem value of the drop-down control to a Property in your ViewModel, then avoid setting the property to other than default value in constructor.

This way it will not show any other item, because your SelectedItem property is null.

EDIT:

If I understand you correctly you could do something like this (I'm using Windows Phone Toolkit at http://phone.codeplex.com/

```
<toolkit:ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Then your ViewModel could lokk like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList{get;set;}

public string MySelectedItem{
    get{ return _mySelectedItem; }
    set{ _mySelectedItem = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have some example how it can be done ?  Thank you in advance.